# What is the area under the graph for decelerating objects?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

For a deceleration in 7 seconds which area do we use?

[image: Graphs]

Do we use the area for the triangle or do we include even the area under the triangle which makes it area of a trapezium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance travelled in the first $7$ seconds is the whole area under the velocity/time graph from $0$ to $7$ seconds i.e. option B, the trapezium.